# Authenticating with Google without using redirects

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, google-api

I've been implementing an OAuth login via the Google Identity toolkit in php. I've got as far as getting an authenticated session, the userdata, id, photo etc, which seems to be working more or less ok.

However, I'd like to be able to login using methods that don't rely on redirection on the user's browser (thinking of remote APIs for an application), but bit lost on how to achieve this.

Imagine a request which is something like:

```
$details = new stdClass();

$details->secret        = $config->secret;
$details->client_id     = $config->client_id;
$details->app_name  = 'my awesome oauth app';

$details->login              = array();
$details->login['email']     = 'some google account email @ example.com';
$details->login['password'] = '1234'; 

$token = $this->do_auth($details);

if($token) {
    // do stuff, setup cookies, insert token in session table etc
}
```

I'm using CodeIgniter. Are there any libraries that can do this..? I've seen android apps doing similar things, using custom login forms, so I'm guessing it's achievable in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You HAVE to redirect, it's a core essential of the way OAuth works, there is no way around this. That's why there is a redirect_uri parameter.

You only have to do this once though: when the user is logging in and you are requesting an access token. After that, you simply use curl for example to request your data.

Comment: yep, been playing with it all day, and realised this too :) it's a very cool system, but the requirement to have some sort of browser thing going on is pretty annoying. Imagine if you wanted to let people register inside an app.. lots of complications. For context, found this article which helped a lot: http://softwareas.com/oauth-openid-youre-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-if-you-think-theyre-the-same-thing